# How can I make an sap.m.TextArea control become responsive when put in an sap.m.Dialog control?

Tags: css, sapui5

I have an sap.m.Dialog control in which I have a few sap.m.IconTabFilter tabs and under one of those tabs I have an sap.m.TextArea element. When I set the width of the TextArea to 100% it works well and almost fills the whole dialog (leaving a little margin on either side). However I noticed that setting the height to 100% does not fill dialog properly. Adjusting the height according to px would solve the issue but I want it to be responsive so that if the size of the dialog changes then the TextArea increases or decreases in height along with the dialog and fills the same area that the dialog does. Is there any way I can solve this? Note that I do not want the dialog itself to be scrollable (only the TextArea) so I have disabled vertical and horizontal scrolling on the dialog.

Comment: you should add your code for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that occurs when the outer container (dialog content area) has its height not specified.

Try to set the dialog property "contentHeight" to a fixed value. It will still be resizable.

```
<Dialog id="idDialog" title="Resize Me" contentHeight="25rem" verticalScrolling="false"
 horizontalScrolling="false" resizable="true" draggable="true">
```